# How to send payment requests from an Android TCN SDK connected to a vending machine with a card reader machine using MDB port?

Tags: android, kotlin, serial-port, serial-communication, multidrop-bus

I am trying to send payment requests from an Android TCN SDK connected to a vending machine with a card reader machine using MDB port. However, I am having trouble understanding the steps and commands required to implement this. I have established a connection between the vending machine and the Android device using the MDB protocol and can communicate with the card reader machine. What are the steps and commands required to send payment requests using the MDB protocol?

Specifically, I am looking for guidance on the following:

- How to request payment information from the card reader machine using the MDB protocol.
- How to verify the payment information collected from the user matches the payment information received from the card reader machine.
- How to send a payment request to the card reader machine using the MDB protocol.

I have consulted the official documentation for the Android TCN SDK and the MDB protocol specification, but I am still having trouble understanding the steps and commands required. Can anyone provide me with guidance or code snippets for implementing these steps?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve your problem, I'm having problems with something similar, could you give me a hand?

Comment: @Henrymarcazeballos Hi! Did you have any success with that, would you be so kind to give any hints?